# Javascript Higher order functions: Passing a callback function into filter not working

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to filter out an array's values by those that return true. I have a function called noRepeat which returns true if the given year has no digits repeated, and false otherwise.

I have another function called no_repeats(yearStart, yearEnd) that creates an array of years from start to end. I want to filter out this array by those years that have no digits repeated and I'm not sure why that isn't working. Any ideas? I've included the problem statement as well and in the code I show what my output is versus what it should be.

```
 Write a function, `no_repeats(year_start, year_end)`, which takes a
 range of years and outputs those years which do not have any
 repeated digits.

 You should probably write a helper function, `no_repeat?(year)` which
 returns true/false if a single year doesn't have a repeat.

 Difficulty: 1/5

function no_repeats(yearStart, yearEnd){
    //call no repeats on each year from yearStart to yearEnd and return an array of years that have noRepeat(year) === true
    var yearRangeArr = [];
    var returnArr = [];
    while (yearEnd >= yearStart){
        yearRangeArr.push(yearEnd);
        yearEnd-=1;
    }
    yearRangeArr.filter(function(year){
        return noRepeat(year);
    });
    return yearRangeArr;


}

function noRepeat(year){ //works
    //create an array pushing each year's digits
    // if arr.indexOf(digit) > -1 then the digit already exists, so return false
    // else append the digit, and if no digit repeats, return true
    year = year.toString();
    var repeatArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
        //console.log(repeatArr);
        if (repeatArr.indexOf(year[i]) > -1){ //if the digit exists in arr
            return false;
        }
        else{
            repeatArr.push(year[i]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//var testArr= [1,2,3,4,2];
//console.log(testArr.indexOf(10));

//console.log(noRepeat(1234));
console.log(no_repeats(1234, 1234)); //== [1234]); 
console.log(no_repeats(1123, 1123)); // == []); ANSWER SHOULD BE [], I'M GETTING [1123].
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with higher-order functions.

Comment: You could have found this problem easily by simply stepping through your program with a debugger. If you stopped on the line after your call to `filter`, and examined the variable `yearRangeArr`, you would notice that it hadn't changed, which would have been a great clue for figuring out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns new value, it does not mutate the original object. You have to assign returned value to your variable:

```
yearRangeArr = yearRangeArr.filter(function(year){
    return noRepeat(year);
});
```

Comment: yearRangeArr = yearRangeArr.filter(noRepeat);
    return yearRangeArr;

If I did something like this, does JS already know that filter should be applied to each element in the array without explicitly saying function(year)?

Comment: @Sunny yes. Filter expects a function as an argument, it does not matter whether you pass an anonymous function or simply `noRepeat`. It does not matter as long as the provided function returns a boolean value for the single element of the array.